# Align icon to the right in a table cell?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table cell which contains a text and an icon. I want to align the text on the left and the icon on the right. I tried it like this, but it does not work. The only solution i know would be to create another `td` where i put the icon inside. But i want both, text and icon in one `td`

```css
    table {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Text <span align="right"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i></span></td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: suggest you remove `align="right"` as the align attribute of html elements is deprecated: w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to use

```
style="float:right;"
```

like this:

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table>
<tr>
<td>Text <span style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i></span></td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also as webeno has correctly pointed out in comments, the **[align attribute has been deprecated now.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align)** So try to avoid it.

Comment: suggest you add that the align attribute of html elements is deprecated: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align

Comment: @webeno:- Updated that. Thanks!

Comment: Also be aware to wrap `i` around `span` otherwise your icon won't be vertically aligned.

Answer (score 3):

If you want them in same td(not adding another for icon) you can try this:

```
<td>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;">I stay at left</div>
  <div style="float:right;width:50%;">And I stay at right</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Good solution, i like it.

Comment: I'm glad that i can help.

Answer (score 3):

```css
    table {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Text <span ><i class="fa fa-toggle-on pull-right"></i></span></td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

this is the best way i think...

Answer (score 2):

Just add will make your icon to right side.

```
span {
    float: right;
}
```

Your updated example:

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

td > span {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Text <span><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i></span></td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: suggest you remove `align="right"` as the align attribute of html elements is deprecated: w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align

Comment: @webeno Done it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<style>
/*If not using bootstrap add this to you css*/
 .pull.right{
   float:right;
 }


 <table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td>Text <span><i class="fa fa-toggle-on pull-right">      </i></span></td>
  <td>Test</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: suggest you remove `align="right"` as the align attribute of html elements is deprecated: w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align

Comment: If he doesn't have pull-right class this will not work. If he was using bootstrap it might work but not in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

add one more class in your css

```
table i.fa{
    float: right;
}
```