# TD icon align top right How to do?

Tags: html, css

How can I align close icon to top right corner of TD? I tried align and vertical align attribute but both are not working.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" align="right" vertical-align="top"></i>
            <b>Hello world1!</b>
        </td>
        <td>Hello world2!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world3!</td>
        <td>Hello world4!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What about inverting `<b>Hello world1!</b>` with your `<i>`

Comment: That's not a good idea. Because content start from left side and icon align to right top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align icon to the right in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219871/align-icon-to-the-right-in-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing so. You can `float` it to "right", or you can simply modify the markup and put the icon after the text.

### `float: right`

```css
td > .fa {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" align="right" vertical-align="top"></i>
            <b>Hello world1!</b>
        </td>
        <td>Hello world2!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world3!</td>
        <td>Hello world4!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Modify the markup

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Hello world1!</b>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" align="right" vertical-align="top"></i>
        </td>
        <td>Hello world2!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world3!</td>
        <td>Hello world4!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you need the icon at precisely the top-right corner, you can use absolute positioning.

### `position: absolute`

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.icon-container {
  position: relative;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: -9px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="icon-container">
          <i class="icon fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" align="right" vertical-align="top"></i>
            <b>Hello world1!</b>
            
        </td>
        <td>Hello world2!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world3!</td>
        <td>Hello world4!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can tweak the values of `top` and `right` attributes to your liking.

Comment: bhai superb. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @ShahRushabh Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the result for what you ask, obviously the graphical result is not realy good, probably you should add a margin.

```css
td {
  position:relative;
}
td i {
  position:absolute;
  right:-5px;
  top:-5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <b>Hello world1!</b>
        </td>
        <td>Hello world2!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world3!</td>
        <td>Hello world4!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right` on the icon.

```css
tr td i {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <b>Hello world1!Hello world1Hello world1 Hello world1!Hello world1Hello world1</b>
    </td>
    <td>Hello world2!Hello world2Hello world2Hello world2 Hello world2!Hello world2Hello world2Hello world2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello world3! Hello world3! Hello world3!Hello world3! Hello world3! Hello world3!</td>
    <td>Hello world4! Hello world4! Hello world4!Hello world4! Hello world4! Hello world4!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code achieves what you want to do. But it overlaps with the content. You might want to add some padding just like I did so it will not overlap.

```css
td {
position: relative;
padding: 20px;
}
.tr {
position: absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="tr"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" align="right" vertical-align="top"></i></span>
            <b>Hello world1!</b>
        </td>
        <td>Hello world2!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world3!</td>
        <td>Hello world4!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>CSS</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .cross_icon_lign{
    padding-left: 95px;
    top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .right-align{
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-times cross_icon_lign" aria-hidden="true" align="right" vertical-align="top"></i>
        <b>Hello world1!</b>
      </td>
      <td class="right-align">Hello world2!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td>Hello world3!</td>
      <td class="right-align">Hello world4!</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

[view image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cznuO.png)